# How to escape from current format in summernote?

Tags: html, css, wysiwyg, text-editor, summernote

I am using Summernote (WYSIWYG) editor in my application.
the problem is, when I copy dummy paragraphs or text from somewhere, like Lorem ipsum, it keeps one format.
for example
when I want to add a heading to the 4th paragraph, when I enter text and change it to h1 or h2, it doesn't change, it keeps the current format which is already applied to dummy text.
I want to escape or remove the current format, when I want to put a heading or something else in the middle or anywhere in the text the new or selected format should apply.